# Cannot run composer commands. SSL: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssl, composer-php

I will start by saying I am not a server guy in any way. A colleague has suddenly left our firm and now I am left to resolve a problem - which i don't understand. I am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction.

We have a server running apache, ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 7.2. I am trying to run "composer install" but am getting the following output

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 6 installs, 15 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (v1.0.0): Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)       
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download doctrine/event-manager from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/event-manager/zipball/a520bc093a0170feeb6b14e9d83f3a14452e64b3" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing doctrine/event-manager (v1.0.0): Cloning a520bc093a
```

and there it hangs for hours before finally timing out.

I have run "composer diagnose" and see the following output

```
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.nicolaslopezj/searchable : exact version constraints (1.9.5) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable)
Checking https connectivity to packagist: WARNING
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys: 
Tag Public Key Fingerprint: ****
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: ****
OK
Checking composer version: 

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                            
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL: Connection reset by peer  
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                             
  failed to open stream: operation failed                                                             

diagnose
```

Is anyone able to let me know what is going on and point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is anyone able to assist with this?

Comment: did you resolve this? Please post any fixes you might have found